# is there type trait that show if one type might contain value of other type

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Is there some type trait that checks, if one integral type can hold value of other integral type without data loss?

For example `int32_t` might hold `uint16_t`, `uint8_t`, `int32_t`, `int16_t` and `int8_t`.

However `int32_t` can not hold `uint32_t`, nor `uint64_t` or `int64_t`.

### Update

I made naive solution and I am posting it as answer. I know one can use `std::is_same` but I think this way is more expressive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can take advantage of the existing language rules here.

For *list-initialization*, narrowing conversions are ill-formed. We are trying to detect narrowing conversions. Hence, to the `void_t`!

```
template <class X, class Y, class = void>
struct can_hold : std::false_type { };

template <class X, class Y>
struct can_hold<X, Y,
    void_t<decltype(X{std::declval<Y>()})>>
: std::true_type { };
```

Comment: Interesting that this seems to work on g++, even though g++ for some reason normally treats narrowing conversions as warnings instead of errors.

Comment: @aschepler Perhaps gcc is smarter than we think. Fail the substitution if a narrowing conversion is seen, then *only if no match is found* try to use the failed candidate anyway, with a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Naive solution:

---

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>



template<typename A, typename B>
struct can_hold : std::false_type{};



template<>
struct can_hold<int8_t,int8_t> : std::true_type{};



template<>
struct can_hold<int16_t,int8_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<int16_t,int16_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<int16_t,uint8_t> : std::true_type{};



template<>
struct can_hold<int32_t,int8_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<int32_t,int16_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<int32_t,int32_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<int32_t,uint8_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<int32_t,uint16_t> : std::true_type{};



template<>
struct can_hold<int64_t,int8_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<int64_t,int16_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<int64_t,int32_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<int64_t,int64_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<int64_t,uint8_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<int64_t,uint16_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<int64_t,uint32_t> : std::true_type{};



template<>
struct can_hold<uint8_t,uint8_t> : std::true_type{};



template<>
struct can_hold<uint16_t,uint8_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<uint16_t,uint16_t> : std::true_type{};



template<>
struct can_hold<uint32_t,uint8_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<uint32_t,uint16_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<uint32_t,uint32_t> : std::true_type{};



template<>
struct can_hold<uint64_t,uint8_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<uint64_t,uint16_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<uint64_t,uint32_t> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<uint64_t,uint64_t> : std::true_type{};



template<>
struct can_hold<float,float> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<double,float> : std::true_type{};

template<>
struct can_hold<double,double> : std::true_type{};



int main(){
}
```

Comment: I understand floating point is an added bonus, but you might want to add also integral to floating point conversions (``float`` can hold 16-bit integers and ``double`` can hold 32-bit integers). *Update*: That is, according to minimum requirements / IEEE.

Comment: @ArneVogel but they can be not IEEE 754 conformant =) See, for example, [`is_iec559`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559)

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov I don't understand your point. If an IEEE 754 ``float`` cannot hold any 16-bit integer, you should easily be able to come up with one as a counter example.

Comment: @ArneVogel I meant that there is little reason to implement int to float conversions because C++ gives little guarantees about floating point types. Floating point types can conform to IEEE or can not. `float` need not to be "IEEE 754 float"

Comment: @ArneVogel `sizeof(float) <= sizeof(double)` and `float` values are subset of `double` values. And these points are already used in the answer. Everything else is implementation defined AFAIR.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you are right that C/C++ does not mandate IEEE 754. However, the C standard (and, indirectly, the C++ standard) does mandate a precision of at least 6 decimal digits for ``float`` (``FLT_DIG``) and 10 for ``double`` (``DBL_DIG``). This means the roundtrips I mentioned are guaranteed to be lossless.

Comment: @ArneVogel yeap, it really would hold for 16 and 32 bit integers. Nice catch!